# Unable to Login into WSO2 EI 6.5.0 after editing user-mgt.xml

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, user-management, wso2-esb

I am trying to change admin credentials in WSO2 EI 6.5.0 by following [WSO2 DOC](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+the+System+Administrator).

By using WSO2 Management console, i can able to modify admin password [as described here](https://medium.com/@kosalasananthana/changing-password-in-wso2-carbon-products-5dd5c808587e) in the section called "Change password using the previous password" and can able to login with new password.

I have created new username/password(as "wso2admin" with admin role) in management console and successfully logging in.

I wanna set this new credentials as default admin credentials, So i edited `user-mgt.xml` file configuration as described below

```
 <Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
        <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
        <AdminUser>
            <UserName>wso2admin</UserName>
            <Password>wso2admin</Password>
        </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        !-- Enable username claim retrieve from the UM_USER_NAME in JDBC datasources -->
        <OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>true</OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>
        <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
    </Configuration>
```

after restarting server, i am getting below error and unable to get management console url

```
    [2022-06-06 21:22:09,929] []  INFO - DefaultCryptoProviderComponent 'CryptoService.Secret' property has not been set. 'org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider' won't be registered as an internal crypto provider. Please set the secret if the provider needs to be registered.
[2022-06-06 21:22:09,945] []  INFO - GoogleTokenGenDSComponent Activating GoogleTokengen DS component
[2022-06-06 21:22:10,070] []  INFO - KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2022-06-06 21:22:14,839] [] ERROR - DefaultRealm 4 cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.40Type class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: 4 cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.40Type class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:395)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 4 cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.40
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:339)
        ... 22 more
[2022-06-06 21:22:14,849] [] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:274)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: 4 cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.40Type class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:316)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: 4 cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.40Type class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:395)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 4 cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.4.40
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:339)
        ... 22 more
[2022-06-06 21:22:33,819] []  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

after getting thie ERROR, I tried to replace with default credentials(as "admin" rather than "wso2admin") in same `user-mgt.xml` file which also giving same kinda ERROR.

Note: Embedded H2 Database is in my local system(windows).

Here 2 clarification required.

1. How to recover from this failure, so that i can able to login to management console?
2. How to change default admin credentials (username/password)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ycr mentioned, there is some class reference ERROR in `user-mgt.xml` config file.

1. How to recover from this failure, so that i can able to login to management console?

ERROR in config:

```
<UserStoreManager class="4">
```

Correction in Config:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
```

after made above change, management console url i got in log file and able to login.

2. How to change default admin credentials (username/password)?

I directly put newly created username, password in `user-mgt.xml` config like below.

```
<Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
        <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
        <AdminUser>
            <UserName>wso2admin</UserName>
            <Password>wso2admin</Password>
        </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        !-- Enable username claim retrieve from the UM_USER_NAME in JDBC datasources -->
        <OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>true</OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>
        <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
    </Configuration>
```

PS:

- Unable to delete Old Super admin since that `Delete` Operation is disabled by default. PFB for reference.

[image: unable to delete old Super Admin]

- If you see above image, you could see that For newly created User (admin as role), All Operations like `Change password`, `Assign/View Roles`, `Delete`, `User Profile`  are Disabled by default. Don't know why it happens.

Answer (score 2):

1. This doesn't seem to be related to the user admin changes you did. I assume you have accidently changed a class reference. As you can see in the error user-core is trying to search for a Class named "4". Check all your class references in the Config files you changed. If you can't track them down get a fresh pack and copy the config files back without changes.
2. Easiest way is to change the following in user-mgt.xml. Set the new admin and password. Make sure the username is different from the old one.

```xml
<Configuration>
            <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>new-admin</UserName>
                <Password>new-pass</Password>
            </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            !-- Enable username claim retrieve from the UM_USER_NAME in JDBC datasources -->
            <OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>true</OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>
            <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>
```

Then do a restart. This will add the new super user to the DB. Now login to the carbon console with the new admin and delete the old super admin.

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for your suggestions,
As u suggested, i figure out class reference error. but unable to delete old super admin and i could see that for new user also some of the operations are disabled. kindly check my answer posted above.